# Turn off only specific jQuery listener after first use

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove a specific listener after it has been used once? In this case, it's an on load listener.

```
$("#my_image").on('load', function() {
        // do stuff
        // turn off here        
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) {$(this).trigger('load');}
});
```

I don't want to remove any other listeners that may be attached to the same element. The other questions that I have seen remove ALL listeners that are attached to the element.

Comment: Re duplicate: I think it can be useful to have the same question / answer more than once, but worded differently. I did a Google search and looked at several answers, but did not find the answer that the duplicate link points to. I searched for how to turn off a listener, but didn't think to try the word "fire."

Comment: I agree, that's why it is closed as a dupe rather than deleted. By closing it as a dupe, it stays around and acts as a sign post and source for additional answers for users who visit the main question.

Comment: But why close it at all? Here https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ Jeff Atwood says "it’s OK for duplicate questions to have duplicate answers." It prevents having to click from one question to another for the answer. For this particular question, luckily it got a right answer before it was closed, but if not, then someone who comes across it later would have to click from here to the other question.

Comment: Only if they are logged in. Users who aren't logged in (the vast majority of users) will be automatically redirected to the duplicate target.

Comment: Unfortunately, because this question has an answer (not a new answer, i might add) it doesn't auto redirect.

Comment: Well, good, it shouldn't redirect. Also, sometimes a question will have like ten answers, all of them with many comments, and then some old discussion in the comments about whether this solution supports IE 7. Sometimes it's nice if someone starts a fresher, newer question, even if it's the same. Get straight to today's relevant answer. I think we should careful about too much policing. I sometimes see people asking questions so defensively, trying to not have their question closed by an over-eager policeman.

Comment: This question doesn't have a non-jquery solution, and never will. it is less useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**one**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

```
$("#my_image").one('load', function() {
        // do stuff
        // turn off here        
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) {$(this).trigger('load');}
});
```

From the docs:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type. The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I did not know about "one"

Comment: It's a pretty useful shortcut!